# alias Not able to execute source command

Tags: alias, command, csh

I am trying to define a following alias in my .aliases file.

```
alias sett 'cleartool setview viewXYZ_!*; cd /path_dir1/dir2/; source ./env/script-name'
```

I use it as `sett myview` on commnd prompt when I open a new Terminal.

First 2 commands work but source ... does not.

./env is a sub-directory of dir2

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: How do you know `source` command does not work?

Comment: @HalosGhost:  Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @Gnouc: I know it does not work as the script-name that I tried to source sets path to my tools. Typing 'which tool' I get unrecognized response. Also, when I type 'exit' on prompt I see: ./env/script-name : No such file or directory      message.

Comment: @Sameer: So does `env/script-name` is under `/path_dir1/dir2/` directory?

Comment: @Gnouc: yes, it is under that same path as /path_dir1/dir2 ... I also tried using full path there instead for source command

Comment: @HalosGhost It looks like he's using `csh` or `tcsh`, they don't have shell functions.

Comment: Given the error message, the file `/path_dir1/dir2/env/script-name` doesn't exist. You made a typo, or are mistaken about the path. If you can't figure it out, copy-paste your actual alias definition, the output when you run `pwd; sett something-that-makes-sense; pwd`, and the output of `ls -ld /path_dir1/dir2 /path_dir1/dir2/env /path_dir1/dir2/env/script-name`.

Comment: Is `cd` an alias, too? It looks like something is spawning a new shell and the source command is not run until you exit  that shell.

Comment: Thanks Gillies and Mark.  I could see that the 'cd' command itself is not executing. [btw,  cd is NOT an alias.]         My alias 'sett <name>' is only executing cleartool setview (first command). I checked with 'pwd' that the pwd remains same before and after executing 'sett <name>'. I tried putting a pwd command itself before 'cd .. ' command in alias... but it seems that only First commands gets executed. I am separating commands within alias definition with a ';' ... is that correct?

Comment: @Barmar, good to know! I am not familiar with (`t`)`csh`, and I didn't realize that any shell didn't have functions.

Comment: Again: Edit your question, copy-paste the output of running the alias. Is this csh or tcsh? Do you have the same problem if this is the only line in your `.cshrc`?

Comment: Can you try `alias sett 'cleartool setview viewXYZ_!*; echo 1;cd /path_dir1/dir2/; echo 2;source ./env/script-name; echo 3'` and then run your `sett` command, and see which echo statements get run?

Comment: I just read the `cleartool` documentation. `setview` apparently creates a subprocess. The rest of the alias doesn't execute until that subprocess exits.